# CSS: margin issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Another easy CSS question maybe. Let's see!

We're using Bootstrap to place information items in a grid.

Whenever I try to avoid the lightblue border line from touching the left container border (the one with a shadow) adding some left margin to the class that contains the border-bottom property, the word "Servidores" misses it's place and runs to the right. This is because the extra margin added.

[image: Web app screenshot]

Is there a way to make the border line shorter without adding extra margin to the internal content?

EDIT: Adding some code as per requested:

```
<div class="
            <div class="col-md-4"> 
                <span class="titulo-paneles">CALIDAD</span><span id="calidad-subtitulo" class="goleft titulo-2"></span>
                <div class="row custom-padding-row borde-inferior">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 borde-derecho custom-height text-center"><span id="MES_SLA_DESC" class="titulo-1-small" data-toggle="tooltip">SLA - mes</span><span id="MES_SLA" class="datos-big-info goleft modal-launcher-calidad cursorManito" data-title="SLA MENSUAL" data-id="MES_SLA"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ver detalle">-</span></div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 custom-height text-center"><span id="HOY_SLA_DESC" class="titulo-1-small" data-toggle="tooltip">SLA - hoy</span><span id="HOY_SLA" class="datos-big-info goleft modal-launcher-calidad cursorManito" data-title="SLA DE HOY" data-id="HOY_SLA"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ver detalle">-</span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row custom-padding-row borde-inferior-grueso custom-margin-bottom">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 text-left borde-derecho custom-height"><div id="SERVERS_DESC" class="titulo-1-small" data-toggle="tooltip" style="font-size: 15px">Servidores</div><span id="SERVERS" class="datos-big-info modal-launcher-calidad noTieneDetalles" data-title="Servers" data-id="SERVERS"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ver detalle">-</span></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 text-center borde-derecho custom-height"><div id="GRANJAS_DESC" class="titulo-1-small" data-toggle="tooltip">Granjas</div><span id="GRANJAS" class="datos-big-info  modal-launcher-calidad noTieneDetalles" data-title="Granjas" data-id="GRANJAS"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ver detalle">-</span></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 text-center borde-derecho custom-height"><div id="BD_DESC" class="titulo-1-small" data-toggle="tooltip">BD</div><span id="BD" class="datos-big-info  modal-launcher-calidad noTieneDetalles" data-title="BD" data-id="BD"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ver detalle">-</span></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 text-center custom-height"><div id="RED_DESC" class="titulo-1-small" data-toggle="tooltip">Red</div><span id="RED" class="datos-big-info  modal-launcher-calidad noTieneDetalles" data-title="Red" data-id="RED"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ver detalle">-</span></div>
                </div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.borde-inferior{
padding-bottom: 10px;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
```

}

```
.borde-inferior-grueso{
padding-bottom: 10px;
border-bottom: 2px solid #2aabd2;
margin-left: 3px;
margin-right: 3px;
```

}

Comment: Can you post some code, please?

Comment: Is Servidores contained inside the element of the blue line?

Comment: @ZeusInTexas Added some code, please let me know if is not enough

Comment: @user7733611correct. It's contained inside the div element that has that border I need to shorten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a few ways you can do it.

### Hacky way

Remove the left paddings from `div#SERVERS_DESC` and its parent, and you *should be* good to go, given the code you provided.

### Less-hacky way

You may want to insert a `<hr/>` element right under your row:

```
        <div class="row custom-padding-row borde-inferior-grueso custom-margin-bottom">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 text-left borde-derecho custom-height"><div id="SERVERS_DESC" class="titulo-1-small" data-toggle="tooltip" style="font-size: 15px">Servidores</div><span id="SERVERS" class="datos-big-info modal-launcher-calidad noTieneDetalles" data-title="Servers" data-id="SERVERS"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ver detalle">-</span></div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 text-center borde-derecho custom-height"><div id="GRANJAS_DESC" class="titulo-1-small" data-toggle="tooltip">Granjas</div><span id="GRANJAS" class="datos-big-info  modal-launcher-calidad noTieneDetalles" data-title="Granjas" data-id="GRANJAS"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ver detalle">-</span></div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 text-center borde-derecho custom-height"><div id="BD_DESC" class="titulo-1-small" data-toggle="tooltip">BD</div><span id="BD" class="datos-big-info  modal-launcher-calidad noTieneDetalles" data-title="BD" data-id="BD"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ver detalle">-</span></div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 text-center custom-height"><div id="RED_DESC" class="titulo-1-small" data-toggle="tooltip">Red</div><span id="RED" class="datos-big-info  modal-launcher-calidad noTieneDetalles" data-title="Red" data-id="RED"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ver detalle">-</span></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Here is your new border -->
        <hr class="borde-inferior"/>
```

And the css:

```
hr.borde-inferior {
    border-color: #2aabd2;
    border-width: 2px;
    width: 95%; /* Adjust here */
}
```

Comment: AWESOME. Tried harcoding style padding 0px in both divs and then had to correct the 100% div adding some padding to the left. I'll build some classes. I understand this is a granular way to do it and is not the correct way but I'm learning :)